# window-методы в конструкторе класса

Tags: javascript, классы, методы

Как включить в конструктор класса методы типа `onclick`, `onresize`?
Я пробовал так:

```
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.blabla = blabla;
    
    doSomething() {}
    setSomeSize() {}
    
    (window.onresize = () => {
      this.setSomeSize();
    })();

    (window.onclick = () => {
      this.doSomething();
    })();
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  new Thing();
}
```

`window.onload` конечно работает. А вот `window.onresize` и `window.onclick` нет ((

UPD. Причем я понял, что `window.onresize` вызывается при создании экземпляра, но не работает потом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще почти рабочий вариант, только не нужно методы класса в конструктор совать И навешивание событий на `window` не нужно делать через анонимные функции.

Вот рабочий вариант:

```js
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.blabla = 'blabla';
    window.onresize = () => {
      this.setSomeSize();
    };

    window.onclick = () => {
      this.doSomething();
    };
    }
    doSomething() { console.log(11111111)}
    setSomeSize() {console.log(22222222)}
    

}

window.onload = () => {
  new Thing();
}
```

Comment: Да! Many thanks